# Confusion over Norton equivalent problem

Tags: current, norton

So I have two questions regarding this Norton equivalent circuit problem.
[image]

My first question is regarding io. io is equal to the 1 volt divided by the 5 ohm resistor. Why does that current not split at the intersection where the resistor and the dependent source meet. How is the io current able to travel directly through the resistor?

[image]

Me second question is regarding the isc current. By shorting the circuit, everything is put into parallel. Yet, KCL at node a yields

isc = 10/5 + 2(ix).

What about the ix current flowing through the 4 ohm resistor? In figure 2, node a and b are the same node correct, otherwise everything wouldn't be in parallel. So I'm struggling to understand why the ix current isn't included in the KCL equation.

Comment: Is there a short across the 4_Ohm? Draw your circuit carefully, showing DOTS where you intend connections.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First case:
Since the 4 Ohm resistor is shorted no current is going to pass through it. Thus Ix = 0. Since Ix=0, the current source 2Ix is going to be zero as well which means an open circuit (for a current source). So now you have just one loop circuit with the voltage source 1 V in series with the 5 Ohm resistor.

Second case:
To apply KCL at a node, you sum up the currents of the branches that are connected to that point. In your case, there are three branches connected to *a* point.

Your circuit can be drawn like this:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fVDJ7P.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Look at this [link](https://www.allaboutcircuits.com/textbook/direct-current/chpt-6/kirchhoffs-current-law-kcl/) for more information.

If you want, you can use a different approach and suppose that *a* and *b* points as one point and do your calculations perspectively.

Comment: Thank you very much for clearing the confusion! Redrawing the circuit like that really helped.

Answer (score 1):

In the firs case, Ix current is 0A because 4 Ohms resistor is short (short across the 4\$\Omega\$)

[image]

And in the second case:

[image]

As you can see \$I_{SC} = \frac{10\,V}{5\Omega}+2I_X\$

And \$I_X\$ current flow in the different path. Do not flow through node a and b.

Answer (score 0):

I would like to add that the first thing to do is get your sum total of R
then you can consider that as your divisor 
Then take a voltage reading at the open AB, not the shorted of course
Divide that and it should give you your equivalency
In order to divide current you have to have a parallel branch, your drawing is not clear considering connections.

Answer (score 0):

There are (were?) three conventions to show whether crossing lines show connected nodes. In the drawing the three pairs show the three methods with not connectied on the left and connected on the right.The oldest (I think) is the top pair, the middle pair is most used now, and the bottom pair, like the top, is seldom seen now. [image: schematic connectors]

Neither of the problems make any sense if the middle pair's convention is not the one used - the crossing lines don't connect, even though @RIFF RAFF seems to think the lines do. They're both, at least in part, trick questions, even with the lines not connecting.

OP should use whichever convention was used in his text book or class and submit the "school solution."  His asking questions show that he understands the problems.

Comment: These images are screen shotted and cropped straight from the textbook, we use none of those conventions. I was unaware and will start using the convention when posting.